# "No release manager available for 'null'" spring cloud skipper error while uploading package to skipper

Tags: spring-cloud-skipper

I am getting "No release manager available for 'null'" error when i try to install the manually created,uploaded package using skipper shell with the following command

package install --package-name demo --package-version 1.0.0 --release-name demo

I am using local repo, i have created the package demo and uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with the package you created. The package `kind` has to be `SpringBootApp` in order to qualify and choose the Default release manager from Skipper. What value you have for your package's `kind`?

Comment: i had as below
# package.yml

apiVersion: skipper.spring.io/v1
kind: SkipperPackageMetadata

#template.yml
apiVersion: skipper.spring.io/v1
kind: SpringCloudDeployerApplication

i changed kind as SpringBootApp in package.yml as you suggested and tested but i am getting same error i got before

Comment: i simply followed - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-package-create

Comment: i found the rootcause, i created the folder template instead of "templates":)